# Convert float64 to byte array

Tags: go, type-conversion

How can I convert a float64 variable to big endian encoded byte array?

```
var f float64 = 12.666512
var result []byte = float64ToByte(f);
fmt.Printf("result:%f",result)
```

For the sake of clarity how should I implement `float64ToByte` function in the following playground?

https://play.golang.org/p/LevxCDd7mK

Comment: @Flimzy:I edited the question(big endian).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [math.Float64bits](https://godoc.org/math#Float64bits) to get the `float64` as a `uint64`. Use shifting and conversions on the `uint64` to convert to a desired sequence of bytes.  For example, here's how to encode a float in big endian order:

```
var buf [8]byte
n := math.Float64bits(f)
buf[0] = byte(n >> 56)
buf[1] = byte(n >> 48)
buf[2] = byte(n >> 40)
buf[3] = byte(n >> 32)
buf[4] = byte(n >> 24)
buf[5] = byte(n >> 16)
buf[6] = byte(n >> 8)
buf[7] = byte(n)
```

You can use the [encoding/binary](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary) to convert the `uint64` to bytes instead of writing out the shifts and conversions directly. Here's how to encode the `float64` in big endian order using that package:

```
var buf [8]byte
binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf[:], math.Float64bits(f))
```

The little endian code is:

```
var buf [8]byte
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint64(buf[:], math.Float64bits(f))
```

Here's the big endian implementation of the `float64ToByte` function in the question:

```
func float64ToByte(f float64) []byte {
   var buf [8]byte
   binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(buf[:], math.Float64bits(f))
   return buf[:]
}
```

[playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Dzxy9gn2oj)

Comment: this anwser tells you how to do it, but If you are intrested in why turn a float point number to a uint32, refer to IEEE754 standard for detail.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`binary.Write()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Write) from package `"encoding/binary"` :

```
func float64ToByte(f float64) []byte {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := binary.Write(&buf, binary.BigEndian, f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/XcvM5eaGtU

Comment: Note: The code is correct, but most computers uses little endian: binary.LittleEndian.

Comment: @HelinWang True but if you are inserting into sorted key-value store, like Bolt or Badger, you want big endian.

Comment: For parsing font files, BigEndian is also required. Regardless, the main essence of the answer has been conveyed. As for which endianness to use, it can be modified according to the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Adding yet another flavor to this question.

```
func float64ToBytes(f64 float64) []byte {
    bts := make([]byte, 8)
    (*(*[]float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&bts)))[0] = f64
    return bts
}

func bytesToF64(bts []byte) float64 {
    return *(*float64)(unsafe.Pointer(&bts[0]))
}
```

You could even make it with zero allocation like this

```
func float64ToBytes(f64 float64) []byte {
    var bts []byte
    sh := (*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&bts))
    sh.Data = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&f64))
    sh.Len = 8
    sh.Cap = sh.Len
    return bts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://play.golang.org/p/FO32EmWfjbL

On my system it had to be little endianed:

```
func float64ToByte(f float64) []byte {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    err := binary.Write(&buf, binary.LittleEndian, f)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("binary.Write failed:", err)
    }
    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to [har07](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43693916/9935654), and I don't think a new answer is warranted just because of a difference in endianness. Your response only serves to remind users to be aware of their computer's endianness, but if that's the case, it might be better to just edit har07's answer directly.

Comment: Additionally, your mention of "my system" is not very clear because it represents a subjective viewpoint. Different users may have systems that are not the same as yours, so if it's necessary to mention, I believe teaching users how to [determine their system's endian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53286786/9935654) would be more beneficial.