# Any better way to check endianness in Go

Tags: go, endianness

I am writing a small program to check the endianness using Go:

```
var i int = 0x0100
ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&i)
if 0x01 == *(*byte)(ptr) {
    fmt.Println("Big Endian")
} else if 0x00 == *(*byte)(ptr) {
    fmt.Println("Little Endian")
} else {
    // ...
}
```

I `import "unsafe"` package to convert `*int` to `*byte`.
But as mentioned in https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/:

> Package unsafe contains operations that step around the type safety of Go programs.
>
> Packages that import unsafe may be non-portable and are not protected by the Go 1 compatibility guidelines.

Is there a better way to determine endianness, or do I have to use unsafe package?

Comment: endianness is important when streaming data however typically the transport channel itself will dictate which flavor of endianness is used ... possibly allowing you to avoid above check

Comment: I don't have a big-endian machine to test this, but I think your code only works because your machine is little-endian. that value of 0x01 will not show up in the high order byte of an int (typically 64 bits).  It would work if you changed to uinit16 or just set the int value to 0x01 and change your logic so that the value of 0x01 indicates little-endian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want to do is architecture-specific, and Go doesn't do a whole lot to help you determine your host's byte order as far as I can tell. Your solution using unsafe pointers is probably the best you can do.

If you know the byte order you want to speak in and encode/decode accordingly, you can use the `encoding/binary` package for that: https://godoc.org/encoding/binary#ByteOrder

If you truly need to rely on host byte order, you might be banging your head on a design anti-pattern that you should try to avoid if possible: https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html

Also here's a spirited discussion on golang-nuts about this very topic, with opinions expressed on both sides of the debate: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/3GEzwKfRRQw

That email thread has a suggestion by Russ Cox to just statically define the desired byte order (or the host byte order) using build constraints:

> > For months now our code has had:
> >
> > var hbo = binary.LittleEndian  // hack - we want host byte order!
> >
> > so we can use encoding.Binary to read things.
>
> Put that in a file named byteorder_amd64.go and
>   it stops being a hack.  It need not be in the standard
>   library.

Hope that helps...

Comment: I don't see how this opinionated answer helps when working with, say nftable's match and target expression info data structures. These are encoded in host endianess. Doesn't stackoverflow ask to keep useless opinion out of answers?

Answer (score 19):

Although still relying on the `unsafe` package, Google's TensorFlow API for Go has a nice solution (see [tensor.go](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/go/tensor.go#L488-L505)) for testing the endianness of your machine:

```
var nativeEndian binary.ByteOrder

func init() {
    buf := [2]byte{}
    *(*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(&buf[0])) = uint16(0xABCD)

    switch buf {
    case [2]byte{0xCD, 0xAB}:
        nativeEndian = binary.LittleEndian
    case [2]byte{0xAB, 0xCD}:
        nativeEndian = binary.BigEndian
    default:
        panic("Could not determine native endianness.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this [code](https://github.com/virtao/GoEndian) can help you.

Whith this can check the machine byte order:

```
//true = big endian, false = little endian
func getEndian() (ret bool) {
    var i int = 0x1
    bs := (*[INT_SIZE]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&i))
    if bs[0] == 0 {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: It is similar to what I posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
var bigEndian = (*(*[2]uint8)(unsafe.Pointer(&[]uint16{1}[0])))[0] == 0
```

As an aside, I suspect your original logic is illegal:

```
var i int = 0x0100
ptr := unsafe.Pointer(&i)
if 0x01 == *(*byte)(ptr) {
```

If you cast a `*T` to `unsafe.Pointer` then to another type, `*U`, then `U` and `T` must have an equivalent memory layout. https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer